# Does the startup time of mobile Couchbase make impractical?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase

I have just started exploring [Couchbase Mobile for Android](http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase-mobile-for-android/current) and have been impressed with how far it has progressed.  It would be nice to have an alternative to Android's SQLite which would involve less boilerplate code.

The biggest issue I have experienced so far is the startup time of CouchDB.  I created a simple app which just starts the database and logs the startup time.  The **very first** time the app is run, it takes **10 seconds** between the call to start it and the callback indicating CouchDB is ready (on a Samsung Captivate).  If the app is killed and restarted, this time reduces to **5 seconds** which isn't too bad. **I am concerned that this will impact usability, even if a splash screen and/or progress dialog is being displayed**.

I would like to know how people are handling this long startup time.  **Does it have a big impact on usability?  Is there a way to make it manageable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <strike>TouchDB</strike> Couchbase Lite instead of Couchbase Mobile. It will cut the startup time from 5-10 seconds to 100 miliseconds. Read the Why-TouchDB document referenced below for the trade offs (It is not an exact replacement) and more detailed information.

Here a paraphrase of the startup time related information from https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS/wiki/Why-TouchDB%3F

> Couchbase Mobile's code size (~4MB) and startup time (5-10 sec on
>   typical devices) are serious problems, which deter some developers.
>
> TouchDB meets the following requirements: Quick startup time on
>   relatively-slow CPUs; ideally 100ms or less.

Edit: TouchDB has been renamed Couchbase Lite

Comment: It looks like Couchbase Mobile is abandoned at this point too.

Comment: Yeah, the last commit is 11 months ago.

Comment: A clarification on names: Couchbase Mobile is the older system, which was replaced by TouchDB. TouchDB more recently got renamed to Couchbase Lite, which is the current embedded version.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version? They have recently reduced the install time by a significant amount.

Comment: I am using the 1.0 Developer Preview, which is the current version.

Answer (score 0):

The sentiment from others using Couchbase is that the times I am seeing might be slightly high and not unreasonable to have a user wait for it to load.  There is further discussion on the [Mobile Couchbase list](http://groups.google.com/group/mobile-couchbase/browse_thread/thread/e6f7092df931a191/812a4467cbc349d1#812a4467cbc349d1).